# SSRS 2008 - Document Map Label when exported to Excel works differently than when in SSRS

Tags: visual-studio, ssrs-2008

SSRS 2008, document map label navigates as expected in SSRS; however, when exported to Excel it does not.

Example: The tablix has a row grouping and via the properties has a page break per that (i.e., on Client Group, see Snippet link below). When I run the report and click the document map label name it takes me to the first item in the Client Group (as expected). When exported to Excel, it takes me to the last item in the Client Group... which I don’t want.

[Snippet of Advanced Group Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TI4zt.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Thank you SO, I've read the info. per the provided links and have edited my post a bit.